# Como accedo a mi objeto en JSON con JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonobject

Buenas tengo la siguiente función que me devuelve un JSON estoy trabajando con jQuery solo que no sé cómo acceder a mi id (objeto) en mi JSON ya que solo quiero que me muestre esa parte del JSON :

```
   function scaner(){
       var lista =  $('#listaProductos').val();
       codigo = $('.codigo').attr('id');
           var obj = JSON.parse(lista); 
           for (var i=0; i< obj.length; i++)
           {
               var codigos = obj[i];
               console.log(JSON.stringify(codigos));
           }

   }
```

el **console.log** me arroja lo siguente: `{"id":"1243","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE NE","cantidad":"1","stock":"1","precio":"250","total":"250"}`  yo solo quiero mostrar el id

Comment: ¿te refieres a `console.log(codigos.id);`?

Answer (score 1):

console.log(JSON.stringify(codigos.id));